# Can't get Firebase data in Polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

I tried to get my Firebase data but firebase-query always returns empty array.

First of all, in my Firebase data looks like

```
/skills
 |___ polymer
 |___ angular
 |___ react
```

Second, my Polymer code is like below:

And I didn't make mistakes in auth-domain, database-url and api-key parts.

```
<firebase-app
  name="pick-me-up"
  auth-domain="auth-domain"
  database-url="db-url"
  api-key="my-key">
</firebase-app>

<firebase-query
  id="query"
  app-name="pick-me-up"
  path="/skills/"
  data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" as="skill">
  <li class="item">{{skill}}</li>
</template>
```

and the script code is:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'pick-me-up-skills',

  properties: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true
    }
  },

  observers: [
    '_dataChanged(data.*)'
  ],

  _dataChanged: function(newData, oldData) {
    console.log(newData);
  }
});
```

And I also change my Firebase rules to read:

```
{"rules":{".read":true,".write":"auth != null"}}
```

I really don't know which part is wrong. In console, `newData` is always equal to `[]`.

Comment: Can you include your import statements? I'm 99% sure I know your problem because I tripped over it several times, too.

Comment: @zacharytamas I included my import statements. Is there anything you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
<firebase-app
    auth-domain="glass-turbine-148103.firebaseapp.com"
    database-url="https://glass-turbine-148103.firebaseio.com"
    api-key="[secret]">
</firebase-app>
<firebase-document
    id="documentStores"
    path="/[[saleBranch]]/stores"
    data="{{stores}}">
</firebase-document>
<firebase-query
    id="queryProducts"
    path="/[[saleBranch]]/products"
    data="{{products}}">
</firebase-query>
```

here `saleBranch` is: "update-sale-quanity-demo"

I also encounter this problem, but it works after remove `app-name` from  element

Wrong `path` also cause error, you may try remove `/` from path

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't put firebase-app and firebase-query elements into same file.

Now, I put it into same file then it works.

But I have 1 more question.

Can I split these element into different files?

If I need other query in other files, should I put firebase-app element in each file again?

These are my import statements...

In pick-me-up-app.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">

<link rel="import" href="pick-me-up-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
```

And in pick-me-up-skills.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="pick-me-up-skill-card.html">
```

pick-me-up-skills elements is just page in pick-me-up-app.

First I put firebase-app into pick-me-up-app.html file.

And I put firebase-query into pick-me-up-skills file.

But it doesn't work, so I move firebase-app into pick-me-up-skills file.

And then it works.